# Cuda strange bug

Tags: c++, cuda

I am having troubles understanding a bug that I have in a simple Cuda kernel. I shrinked down my kernel to the minimum that still shows the error.

I have a "Polygon" class that just stores a number of points. I have a function that "adds a point" (just increments the counter), and I add 4 points to all polygons in my array of polygons. Finally, I call a function that updates the number of points using a loop. If, in this loop, I call `new_nbpts++` once, I obtain the expected answer : all polygons have 4 points. If in the same loop I call `new_nbpts++` a second time, then my polygons have a garbage number of points (4194304 points) which is not correct (I should get 8).

I expect there is something I misunderstood though.

Complete kernel:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>


class Polygon {
public:
  __device__ Polygon():nbpts(0){};
  __device__ void addPt() {
    nbpts++;
  }; 
  __device__ void update() {
    int new_nbpts = 0;
    for (int i=0; i<nbpts; i++) {
        new_nbpts++;
        new_nbpts++;  // calling that a second time screws up my result
    }
    nbpts = new_nbpts;
  }

 int nbpts;
};


__global__ void cut_poly(Polygon* polygons, int N)
{
  int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
  if (idx>=N) return;

  Polygon pol;
  pol.addPt();
  pol.addPt();
  pol.addPt();
  pol.addPt();

  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    pol.update();
  }

  polygons[idx] = pol;
}



int main(int argc, unsigned char* argv[])
{
  const int N = 20; 
  Polygon p_h[N], *p_d;

  cudaError_t err = cudaMalloc((void **) &p_d, N * sizeof(Polygon));   

  int block_size = 4;
  int n_blocks = N/block_size + (N%block_size == 0 ? 0:1);
  cut_poly <<< n_blocks, block_size >>> (p_d, N);

  cudaMemcpy(p_h, p_d, sizeof(Polygon)*N, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

  for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
   printf("%d\n", p_h[i].nbpts);

  cudaFree(p_d);

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you doing this at the end of your kernel:

```
  for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
    pol.update();
  }
```

?

Remember each thread has it's own instance of:

Polygon pol;

If you want to update each thread's instance of pol at the end of the kernel, you only need to do:

```
pol.update();
```

Now, what happens in your case?

Suppose your update() code only has one:

```
new_nbpts++;
```

in it.

Your for loop of 0 to N-1 calling pol.update() will, on each iteration:

1. set new_nbpts to zero
2. increment new_nbpts a total of nbpts times.
3. replace the value of nbpts with new_nbpts

Hopefully you can see this has the effect of leaving nbpts unchanged.
Even after N iterations of the for loop that is calling pol.update(), the value of nbpts is unchanged.

Now what happens if I have:

```
new_nbpts++;
new_nbpts++;
```

in my update() method?  Then on each call of pol.update(), I will:

1. set new_nbpts to zero
2. increase new_nbpts by two a total of nbpts times
3. replace the value of nbpts with new nbpts

Hopefully you can see this has the effect of doubling nbpts *on each call of pol.update()*

Now, since you are calling pol.update() N times *in each thread*, you are doubling the starting value of nbpts N times, i.e. nbpts *2^N.  Since nbpts starts out (in this case) as 4, we have 4*2^20=4194304

I'm not really sure what you're after with all this, but my guess is you were running that for loop at the end of the kernel thinking you were going to update all the different instances of Polygon pol that way.  But that's not how to do it, and all you need is a single

```
pol.update();
```

at the end of the kernel, if that was your intention.

Comment: Looping over all possible N for each thread is actually what I want to do (each thread manages on point, and each point needs to access all of the other points).
Now, I don't understand your argument that the number of points doubles each time : each thread has its own instance of a Polygon, which starts at 4 points, and should end with 8 points (each), isn't it ?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry I understand about the number of points doubling each time... I'll try to fix that (but looping over all other points is still what I want to do ;) )  - that was rather a stupid question ;)

Comment: Your `Polygon pol;` is local to each thread.  I'm not sure why you think calling `pol.update();` N times in a row would access N different instances.  C++ doesn't work that way.  If you want each thread to access each of the other instances of `Polygon pol;` you will need to put those in shared or global memory and arrange an indexed access system of some sort.

Comment: yep - I totally agree. I think I just shrank down my original code too much, to the point that my original bug is not showing up anymore but I instead did a silly mistake in this reduced code. Having a local polygon for each thread was intended though. Thanks

Comment: (for more information, the more general code is at : http://codepad.org/LQdWcS1c and my polygons all end up with 0 vertices. This implements Sutherland–Hodgman polygon clipping in parallel for many vertices to produce a voronoi diagram, but it has a bug - which is now beyond the scope of this simple stackoverflow question)